# Angular : Click Binding is not Working on Dynamic Invoking Click Event anchor Tag

Tags: angular, data-binding, click

I got a problem with Angular(2+),
I have a  menu with anchor tag, we manually select menu item or through keyboard Enter  we select the menu item.

```
<a (click) = 'selectItem(item)' id='menuItem1'>Menu item</a>
```

Through Enter, dynamically calling the click event on anchor tag.

```
$('#menuItem1').click();
```

Expecting that menu has to select, but not selected. 
Other than anchor tag, on **Enter** menuitem is selected.

Sample Code :
https://plnkr.co/edit/lZX86z7xIBdrvI9lNEFO?p=preview

Please help me.

Question :

1) Why Jquery click is not working on anchor tag along with angular bindings?
2) Why working for other tags (than anchor tag)?

Comment: Read about angular lifecycle hooks.

Comment: It is not related to hooks, how angular register click binding to elements?That may answer my problem.

Comment: Why is your plunker different with your code?

Comment: `how angular register click binding to elements` You need to think about how jquery executes `click` method

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yx82Lxfy/

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps alot

Answer (score 0):

its look like changing the 'click trigger' code to native js - it is strating to work

```
document.querySelector("#anchorTag").click();
```

[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kyUKDRZKQspRhYSYqshw?p=preview)

Comment: That's working, but my question is why jquery click event is not working? how angular implement click binding? It's working with other tags rather than anchor tag?